# Data wrangling in efficient way (Stock data)

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Here are the codes that I start with:

```
library(quantmod)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)


mdate <- "2019-05-01"
edate <- "2019-05-03"
tickers <- c("MMM","C", "AAPL")


for(ticker in tickers)
 Open_Raw <- cbind(Open_Raw, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)[,1])


timetk::tk_tbl(Open_Raw)

Open_Raw <- timetk::tk_tbl(Open_Raw)[, -1]
colnames(Open_Raw) = tickers

## Open Price
Open_Raw <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers)
  Open_Raw <- cbind(Open_Raw, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)[,1])
Topen_Raw <- t(Open_Raw)

## High Price
High_Raw <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers)
  High_Raw <- cbind(High_Raw, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)[,2])
Thigh_Raw <- t(High_Raw)

## Low Price
Low_Raw <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers)
  Low_Raw <- cbind(Low_Raw, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)[,2])
Tlow_Raw <- t(Low_Raw)

## write in the same way for Close, Adjusted and Volume, and;


##Cbind Open and High
Open_High <- cbind(Topen_Raw, Thigh_Raw)

##Cbind Open_High and Low_Raw
Open_to_Low <- cbind(Open_High, Tlow_Raw)
```

As you see the output, first two columns are Open price and, third and fourth columns are High price. I can have the output what I want with those codes, but there are errors when I try to import thousands stock data, so I cannot use those. If it is possible I want to make a space between the data set(Open, High, Low, Close, Adjusted and Volume)

What can I do to do this?

Comment: Do you want to have separate dataframes for open , high, low, close etc? Or something like this work `Rawdata %>%
  rownames_to_column('Date') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date,names_to = c('ticker', '.value'), names_sep = '\\.')`

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you so much again!! I just ran the code and got an error: Error in rownames_to_column(., "Date") : 
  could not find function "rownames_to_column"     Do I need to activate any package or something? I want that all of the data is shown in one page like the picture I uploaded.

Comment: Yes, `rownames_to_column` is from `tibble` and `pivot_longer` is from `tidyr`. If you already have `tidyverse` installed you can do `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: I'm sorry Ronak to bother you. The format that I want is excatly like second picture. Column name is date and each box is consisted with tickers(row names) and stock data. The first three columns have only open price as you see. And from fourth and sixth columns have only high prices. I deeply thank you about your help. This is what I have tried for a month alone.

Comment: Well, R is different than excel. "Exactly as picture" is not a good way to share expected output. Try to create your expected output manually in R and then post it here which would be helpful to know what you want.

Comment: I edited my questions. Can you see what I tried to make? Unfortunately I cannot use those code because there are errors when I try to download thousands stock data. The way you gave me is perfect. I want to have an output like I just posted by using your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
# Transpose data.frame: 
td_data <- within(data.frame(price_var = row.names(t(data)), t(data), row.names = NULL), 
                  {
                    ticker_cd <- as.factor(gsub("[.].*", "", price_var))
                    price_var <- as.factor(gsub(".*[.]", "", price_var))
                  }
                )
# Reshape: 
do.call("cbind", split(td_data, td_data$price_var))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but this is not what I try to create. Thank you again hello_friend

Comment: @DongchulPark please look into the `xtabs` function.

Comment: hello_friend, Would you mind to explain me this part?;  "price_var <- as.factor(gsub(".*[.]", "", price_var)" I looked up many things about gsub, and tried to see the difference by using your codes. I couldn't find what it tells about.

Comment: We remove every character after the period in order to create the ticker vector (from the rownames) then from the price_var we remove the values from the ticker vector. This allows us to split on the price_var and retain all the required information. We cast to factor because this is the appropriate type for both vectors as they have a discrete set of values.

Comment: @DongchulPark No worries please upvote my solution if it does what you require !

Comment: hello_friend, would you mind to see my another question that I posted on May 29th? I would really appreciate if you help me out.

Comment: I'm so sorry to ask you again. I got an error from the codes that you wrote. Would you please see my question that I just posted?